# How do you plot two vectors on x-axis and another on y-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r

I am trying to plot two vectors with different values, but equal length on the same graph as follows:

```
a<-23.33:52.33
b<-33.33:62.33
days<-1:30

df<-data.frame(x,y,days) 

      a   b    days
 1    23.33 33.33    1
 2    24.33 34.33    2
 3    25.33 35.33    3
 4    26.33 36.33    4
 5    27.33 37.33    5
 etc..
```

I am trying to use ggplot2 to plot x and y on the x-axis and the days on the y-axis. However, I can't figure out how to do it. I am able to plot them individually and combine the graphs, but I want just one graph with both a and b vectors (different colors) on x-axis and number of days on y-axis.

What I have so far:

```
X<-ggplot(df, aes(x=a,y=days)) + geom_line(color="red")
Y<-ggplot(df, aes(x=b,y=days)) + geom_line(color="blue")
```

Is there any way to define the x-axis for both a and b vectors? I have also tried using the melt long function, but got stuck afterwards.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(a,days),colour="red") + geom_line(aes(b,days),colour="blue")

Comment: That works great. Thank you. still getting around to using ggplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do it is via a the approach of melting the data (as you have mentioned). Especially if you are going to add more vectors. This is the code

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

a<-23:52
b<-33:62
days<-1:30

df<-data.frame(x=a,y=b,days)
df_molten=melt(df,id.vars="days")

ggplot(df_molten) + geom_line(aes(x=value,y=days,color=variable))
```

You can also change the colors manually via `scale_color_manual`.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is to use only ggplot. The following code will work in your case

```
a<-23.33:52.33
b<-33.33:62.33
days<-1:30

df<-data.frame(a,b,days) 

ggplot(data = df)+
geom_line(aes(x = df$days,y = df$a), color = "blue")+
geom_line(aes(x = df$days,y = df$b), color = "red")
```

I added the colors, you might want to use them to differentiate between your variables.